# How to make a webservice in RTMFP? (and.. how it works)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web-services, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

I managed (thanks to an example I saw in adobe labs) to host in my webpage an swf, and through Cirrus I could establish a connection between two different users, that worked like a charm, BUT, I had to pass through msn the peer ID in order to establish that connection.

I know that this part must be resolved by a webservice.. but, how can I make one, and, more important, how does it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you how to do that with PHP

1) First you need a website or online-"localhost" (put online option available on WAMP)

2) Using HTTPService in FLEX , pass your nearID to PHP script and make that script write that value to backend. (MySQL)

3) When your friend connects to your site , do the same as step 2.

4) Exchange your IDs from the backend again using PHP script.

Now you will be connected.